# Side menu with links to parts in Iframes

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've created a webpage that has the following structure:

Main html that uses a side menu;
Secondary html that has the information that I want to show in the main html.

I want to achieve the following. Let's say that the secondary html has a section named intro. I want to link that section to a menu item. So when I press the corresponding button, I want to show in my main html the secondary html starting at the #intro section.

This is my sidebar nav in the main html

```
<div id="main">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- LEFT SIDEBAR NAV-->
            <aside id="left-sidebar-nav">
                <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav leftside-navigation">
                    <li class="no-padding">
                        <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
                            <li class="bold"><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-blue active"><i class="mdi-action-view-carousel"></i> Field</a>
                                <div class="collapsible-body">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#intro">Intro</a>
                                        </li> 
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
            </aside>
       </div>
```

This is the section in the 2nd html.

```
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section" id="intro">

        <li style="list-style: disc">
            some text.
        </li>
</div>
</div>
```

When I press the Intro button in the left side nav, I want to open in my main html the 2nd one at the Intro section.

The reason I want to load the 2nd html in my main one is that It uses different css styles and It ruins my formatting if I merge them.

Any solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Need a [mcve], it would be easier to understand what the hell you are talking about if you posted more than one line of code.

Comment: Just to clarify: where do you want  to load your content when the user click the link? in another place of the page, or under your menu (like a submenu) ?

Comment: Hi. In another place of the page, baasically I want the 2nd html to look like it's one and the same with the main html. I tried with:             <iframe src="secondary.html#intro" style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"></iframe> But It just directs the user to the 2nd html. I want it to be loaded in my main one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily achieved with [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com/):

Here's my suggestion:

### Step 1

First of all, make sure you have those sections in your `secondary.html` file:

```
<div id="intro">Intro section</div>
<div id="section1">Section 1</div>
<div id="section2">Section 2</div>
<div id="section3">Section 3</div>
```

An, in `main.html`, make sure you have an element with `id=content`. This will be your placeholder. Like this:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

### Step 2

Modify your anchors:

1. point `href` to a dummy url (`#`).
2. add a class so we can catch this with jQuery. I named here `btn-load-section`.
3. add [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attributes so we can add some useful data to each anchor, to grab it later. I added here `data-url` and `data-section`.

Like this:

```
<li><a href="#" class="btn-load-section" data-url="secondary.html" data-section="intro">Intro</a>
<li><a href="#" class="btn-load-section" data-url="secondary.html" data-section="section1">Section 1</a>
<li><a href="#" class="btn-load-section" data-url="secondary.html" data-section="section2">Section 2</a>
<li><a href="#" class="btn-load-section" data-url="secondary.html" data-section="section3">Section 3</a>
```

### Step 3

At the end of our `<body>` section (in `main.html`), you can add this code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /*
        Executes the script inside the anonymous function 
        only when the page is loaded
    */
    $(document).ready(function() {

        /* 
            select all anchors with 'btn-load-section' class (class = dot before)
            and bind a click event
        */
        $("a.btn-load-section").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //this cancel the original event: the browser stops here

            var url = $(this).data('url'); //get the data-url attribute from the anchor
            var section = $(this).data('section'); //get the data-section attribute from the anchor

            var contentDiv = $("#content"); //select the div with the ID=content (id = hash before). This will be our target div.

            /*
                executes the jQuery .load function
                It will load the url and search for the correspondent section (load page fragment)
                e.g. will call load with "secondary.html #intro" (#intro is our fragment on the secondary.html page).
            */
            contentDiv.load(url + " #" + section); 


        });

    });
</script>
```

As I don't know how familiar you're with jQuery, I added some comments.

The first script tag loads jQuery from a CDN.

You can read more about the jQuery's `.load` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/). But basically it allows to load page fragments:

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a **portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted**. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

This is just a possible approach. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi. Briliant work! I tested on a simple html and it worked but in my files, once I add <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> at the end of <body> the sidebar fails to work (it just doesn't open anymore). I will accept the answer because I understood the concept. I just need to find a workaround for the new problem.

Comment: Thanks! You can check console if there are some errors.

Comment: I checked them but i'm not that familiar with jquery. Here is the error:Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
    at r.fn.init.r.fn.load (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (plugins.min.js:1)
    at j (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)

Comment: Maybe your actual document already loads jQuery somewhere. You can check *Network Tab* in the *Developer Tool* if jQuery is being loaded sometime. If so, you can remove one of them and give it a try.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed it, now I get: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. This project that I'm working is offline, it's not on a server yet.

Comment: If you're using linux, I suggest using this utility: [`http-server`](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server). Just run `http-server` from your folder and it sets up a simple server to serve your files.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help. I tested your suggestion to use http-server and it works. One little problem that I couldn't see when i tested the method in my simple example. I want to display the whole 2nd html in my main one but scrolled to the intro section. Is like mirroring the whole html file in my main one but scrolled on the intro section ( like little shortcuts to the section so the user wont have to search it with scroll. Thank you!

Comment: Let me refrase it. I want to do a jump link. So currently I'm using iframe to mirror the 2nd html in my main one. From my main one (where I have my left nav) I want to jump link to a certain topic in the iframe.